# How to send email in c# with Port id 465 and ssl "true"

Tags: c#

Can't send email by using this code,
Exception thrown "The Operation has time out."
Code:

```
MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress("xxx@gmail.com");
mailMessage.From = new MailAddress("yyy@domainName.com", "No-Reply");
mailMessage.Subject = "Test Mail";
mailMessage.Body = "E-Mail Testing...........";
mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;

SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
//client.Timeout = 200000;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Credentials = 
   new System.Net.NetworkCredential("yyy@domainName.com", "--Password--");
client.Port = 465;
client.Host = "mail.domainName.com.np";
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.EnableSsl = true;
client.Send(mailMessage);
```

Comment: You have specified `ssl = True`. Is SSL configured on your server?

Comment: Any number of reasons could cause this, the server could be unreachable, the ports may not be open, the server may not have SSL configured. I would recommend trying to see if your data is being sent using a tool like wireshark,

Comment: Consider using TLS port maybe: `587`.

Answer (score 0):

The `EnableSsl` option will NOT implicitly use SSL. That means it will not immediately begin SSL negotiations after connecting.

The `EnableSsl` option will enable explicit SSL. Which means SSL will be negotiated with the server using the `STARTTLS` command as described in [RFC 3207](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3207.txt).

`System.Net.Mail` does not support implicit SSL. You may have another port available from the server that you can use explicit SSL on. Otherwise you have to reconfigure your server.